# c# uint to ushort overflow like in native C

Tags: c#, integer-overflow

I have the following piece of example code:

```
UInt16 a = 0x3A;
UInt16 b = 0xFFDF;
UInt16 result = Convert.ToUInt16(a - b);
```

line 3 errors with an Overflow exception. However i want to achieve the same result like i would subtract 2 unsigned shorts in C and they over/underflow.

What is the most proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could mask lower 16 bits as follows:

```
UInt16 result = Convert.ToUInt16((a - b) & 0xffff);
```

Comment: You can also use the [unchecked context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/a569z7k8.aspx): `ushort result = unchecked((ushort)(a-b));`